# Validations to be done before js function call on button in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some text fields and a button on my aspx. The text fields are validated using required field validators. On button i have set OnClientClick() event to do certain JS operations.

The problem here is that, the JS function is called before validations are completed. That is i need to validate first and then call js on client click event of button.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the client side validation manually:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate()) return YourFunction(); else return false;"
    OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Remember to do whatever checking server side as well since you javascript could be manipulated and/or bypassed.